# What are some must know Gems that new learning programmers and new Rubyists should explore?

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I've recently started learning programming and development utilizing Ruby as my language of choice.

As I expand the scope of my learning, I want to start thinking about practical little projects to help enforce what I'm learning. What are some interesting or popular Gems that I should be aware of, or explore as a beginner programmer in the world of Ruby code writing?

Thanks all.

Comment: I guess the question is off topic here. However, check here: https://rubygems.org/stats

Comment: These sorts of tool recommendation questions are off-topic here because they're highly subjective and there's no correct answer, only opinions and suggestions. Consider posting on [Dev.to](https://dev.to) or another site that's better suited to discussion and debate.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

While there are a TON of gems out there that all have great uses, here are a few that I've found to be useful in almost every Ruby on Rails app I've taken part in. This list is by no means exhaustive:

**Devise** - `gem 'devise'`
For user authorization, account creation, form validation. Provides Model - View - Controller files for more customization, and is an easy way to add another of abstraction for user info.

**Faker** - `gem 'faker'`
Random information generation. This is extremely useful in testing where you would want to say, create a user with a random email, name, phone number. There are even a ton of fake pop culture information (Game of Thrones, Harry Potter, League of Legends).

**ChartKick** `gem 'chartkick'`
Easy way to generate nice looking interactive graphs/charts with your data.

**Will Paginate** `gem 'will_paginate'`
Let's say you have 2000 users to load on a page, this may take a couple of seconds to load up. With Will Paginate you can load a smaller number at a time, and have the rest stored in other pages.

**Kaminari** `gem 'kaminari'`
Another pagination tool that allows for clean and easy to use pages. Uses the  tag and ActiveRecord.

**Twilio** `gem 'twilio-ruby'`
Twilio is a text messaging service that can send messages from either long or short codes. This has been useful for me when alerting users of account changes/updates. Does cost a small amount of money to use, however.

**Carrier Wave/Image Magick/Mini Magick** `gem 'carrierwave', gem 'image_magick', gem 'mini_magick'`
If you need a light weight image uploader/compressor/resizer these gems go really well together to have full image control. *ActiveRecord is now default in RoR, another tool*

I've had personal experience with all of these and found they were useful/intriguing in some way. There are so many more out there, and you can visit https://rubygems.org/ if you ever want more documentation on any of these.

Comment: Don't forget [Kaminari](https://github.com/kaminari/kaminari) and that Rails now has [ActiveStorage](https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_storage_overview.html) which makes CarrierWave optional.

Comment: @tadman thanks! added those edits